# Mirror two data frames

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, data-frame

Is it possible to link two data frames so that they mirror each other?  I know I can set the extent of one data frame to that of another data frame, but then you can only pan/zoom in the parent frame.  Basically just want the two data frames to mirror one another.

I would like the flexibility to pan and zoom in which ever data frame is active, not just the "parent" data frame.  This is different from setting the extent of one data frame to match that of another, where only the parent data frame has the ability to pan and zoom.  I am using ArcMap 10.1.

I have made this suggestion to ArcGIS Idea: [Mirror Data Frames - ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000005IKmIAM)

Comment: Are you looking for this to work dynamically, or is the end result a printed/exported map?

Comment: I would like for them to work dynamically.

Comment: Based on the question, and the possible duplicate Dan C mentioned, I would say you are stuck with only matching extents and only being able to change the extent in the parent data frame. What's your use case for needing to be able to pan/zoom in both data frames?

Comment: I saw this, but I don't think it is what I am looking for.  I would like for data frame 1 and 2 to follow each other.  If I pan or zoom in data frame 1 then data frame 2 does the same.  If I pan or zoom in data frame 2 then data frame 1 does the same.  If I were to set the extent of data frame 2 to match data frame 1, then it is only possible to move around in the parent data frame (data frame 1).

Comment: I think I am stuck.  I was hoping to use the first data frame to pin point an "area of interest" and zoom to that area, then pan around in the second data frame.  I would like to keep the data in the two data frames separate if possible.  I might have to create a work around using a range scale for layers to be shown.

Comment: One method that isn't fully dynamic, is to use a Viewer Window.  You could open a viewer on one data frame and zoom around.  Then just choose zoom map to viewer to get the other data frame at the same extent.  This works alright if the viewer window data frame is only being used for a reference. It also works handy if you have multiple monitors because you can place your viewer window on another screen.

Comment: I think the Viewer Window might be a decent work around.  Of course I would prefer for it to be fully dynamic, but it is very serviceable for now.  Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please? You mention data frames so I assume you want to do this in ArcMap rather than the ArcGIS Pro application.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS for Desktop, 10.1.  I will be using this in ArcMap, not ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Baltok:

> One method that isn't fully dynamic, is to use a Viewer Window. You
>   could open a viewer on one data frame and zoom around. Then just
>   choose zoom map to viewer to get the other data frame at the same
>   extent. This works alright if the viewer window data frame is only
>   being used for a reference. It also works handy if you have multiple
>   monitors because you can place your viewer window on another screen.

If you require more than this workaround then I recommend that you submit an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com) and post its link here. An existing idea entitled [Linked Data Frames](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008I01AAE) does not seem to be what you are after.

Comment: I have made this suggestion to ArcGIS Idea.  The link is in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use **Bookmarks**:

1. Set up your bookmarks whilst **one** data frame is active,
2. **Export** those bookmarks using the `Bookmarks > Manage Bookmarks... > Save > Save All...` button,
3. Activate the **second** data frame and **import** those bookmarks using the `Bookmarks > Manage Bookmarks... > Load...` button,
4. Now both data frames have bookmarks that are the same: loop through the bookmarks as desired by activating each data frame in turn and using the **Bookmarks** menu.